# Physics mystery : why does it rotate?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, thermoelectricity

[image]

In the beginning this thing was floating still and the candle was out. Then someone lit the candle and the flame somehow Made the object spin on the water. 
See the picture.

I know a little bit about thermodynamics and a bit about electromagnetism, but not the combination. Is this due to magnetism or thermodynamics or both? 
Does the flame change The electric field? Is it related to curie temperature and the alike? Please explain this.

Also how to compute the speed of rotation? How long will it spin? How to explain classically and how modern (quantum)?

I assume the properties of water relate?

Comment: In what direction does iT rotate and why ?

Comment: What's with the caps? Why do you bring in all these advanced subjects, bringing this question to an almost spiritual level. Fortunately @John Rennie quickly saw through this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What your GIF doesn't show is that the bottom ends of the copper tube are angled:

[image: Tea-light engine]

The toy is known as a *tea-light engine* and Googling this will find you various sites describing it. The copper tube is full of water. When the candle heats the tube the water at the point where the heat is applied turns to steam and forces water out of the ends of the tube. Since the ends of the tube are bent, the water flowing out of them creates a torque and rotates the whole object.

Comment: I assume it stops rotating because the water gets cooked out of the tube.

Comment: @mick yes, I guess so, though none of the videos I found are long enough to show it running out of water and stopping.